# Internal Microphone not working on HP 625 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp, microphone

I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP 625 laptop - it's great, but...
I still can't use my internal microphone. When I go to Sound Settings
it seems like the alsa plugin detects it, but doesn't register any sound.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Installing Pulse audio volume control from USC and fiddling with its settings got my mic working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In terminal run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add these two lines to the end of `alsa-base.conf` :

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel

options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Save and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Pulse Audio with no success but it seems to have started working after installing Banshee - I can't be sure that was what fixed it but its worth a try.